# Meteor publication Exception: Did not check() all arguments during publisher when using aldeed:tabular

Tags: javascript, meteor, tabular, meteor-publications

I have the following publication:

```
Meteor.publish( 'usersadmin', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find( {}, { fields: { "emails": 1, "roles": 1, "profile": 1 } } )
});
```

and I'm displaying the publication in the following table using [aldeed:tabular](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular):

```
TabularTables.UsersAdmin = new Tabular.Table({
      name: "User List",
      collection: Meteor.users,
      pub: "usersadmin",
      allow: function(userId) {
        return Roles.userIsInRole(userId, 'admin');
      },
      columns: [{
        data: "emails",
        title: "Email",
        render: function(val, type, doc) {
          return val[0].address;
        }
      }, {
        data: "roles",
        title: "Roles",
        render: function(val, type, doc) {
          return val[0]._id;
        }
      }]);
```

The table displays fine, but in the server terminal the following exception shows up:

```
 Exception from sub usersadmin id 2d7NFjgRXFBZ2s44R Error: Did not check() all arguments during publisher 'usersadmin'
```

What causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive this error because you need to check the arguments passed to your `usersadmin` publish function by using **[`check(value, pattern)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check)**.

The reactive DataTables, implemented in the **[`aldeed:tabular`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular)** package, pass the arguments `tableName`, `ids` and `fields` to the publish function; that's why an exception is thrown.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular#using-a-custom-publish-function), you need to take care of the following requirements:

> Your function:
>
> - MUST accept and check three arguments: tableName, ids, and fields
> - MUST publish all the documents where _id is in the ids array.
> - MUST do any necessary security checks
> - SHOULD publish only the fields listed in the fields object, if one is provided.
> - MAY also publish other data necessary for your table

This should fix the error:

```
Meteor.publish('usersadmin', function(tableName, ids, fields) {
  check(tableName, String);
  check(ids, Array);
  check(fields, Match.Optional(Object));
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {"emails": 1, "roles": 1, "profile": 1}});
});
```